Let $F:C\rightarrow D$ and $G:D\rightarrow C$ be functors, such that $F$ is left adjoint of $G$, is that true $X\cong GF(X),\forall X\in C$?

Let $F:C\rightarrow D$ and $G:D\rightarrow C$ be functors, such that $F$ is left adjoint of $G$ i.e. $$\text{Hom}_D(FX,Y)\cong \text{Hom}_C(X,GY),\forall X,Y$$
Then is it true that $X\cong GF(X)$, $\forall X\in C$?

I expect that to be true and I attempted to say that via adjunction we can obtain $$\text{Hom}_C(X,GF(X))=\text{Hom}_D(F(X),F(X))$$
and on the righthand side we know $F(X)\cong F(X)$ hence somehow I expected that on the lefthand side $X\cong GF(X)$ should also be isomorphic. But in the definition of adjunction of functors it is not required that the bijection $\text{Hom}_D(FX,Y)\cong \text{Hom}_C(X,GY)$ necessarily has to associate isomorphism to isomorphism. Hence, I am wondering if this result is true.

There is always a unit $\eta_X:X \to GF(X)$, but that is an isomorphism for all objects $X$ of $C$ if and only if $F$ is fully faithful.

$F$ (resp. $G$) is fully faithful iff $\eta$ (resp. $\epsilon$) is a natural isomorphism iff the bijection $\mathrm{Hom}_D(FX, Y) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_C(X, GY)$ preserves (resp. reflects) isomorphisms.

Asking category theory questions without looking at a single example really misses the point. For example, at least 10 examples on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_functors do not have this property being asked here.

No, it's not true. For example, take $\mathsf{Set}$ and $\mathsf{Group}$, with functor $F\colon\mathsf{Set}\to\mathsf{Group}$ the free group functor, and $G\colon\mathsf{Group}\to\mathsf{Set}$ the underlying set functor. Then $\mathsf{Set}(X,G(B)) \cong \mathsf{Group}(F(X),B)$ for any set $X$ and group $B$.
But $GF(X)$ is the underlying set of the free group on $X$; since $F(X)$ is infinite whenever $X$ is not empty, if $X$ is finite then $GF(X)$ is not bijectable with $X$; and if $X$ is empty then $GF(X)$ is a singleton, so again it is not bijectable with $X$.
